# c# add bytes to bytearray?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

How do I add bytes to a byte array?

Example -

Creating byte array called data

```
public byte[] data;
public int offset;
```

Adding to List created above

```
public void add() {
    //what to do here??
    put1(12); // tried this to add int 12 in bytes to array
    // which i assumed would add a byte to the array
}
```

Sub method I made to add int as 1 byte

```
    public void put1(int var1)
    {
        this.payload[++this.offset - 1] = (byte)var1;
    }
```

Comment: What’s your exact error? Have you even created the byte array for `data`? You say "creating byte array called data" but only show you declaring the byte array but not creating it. Also `++this.offset - 1` is unnecessarily complicated, just do `this.offset++`.

Comment: Arrays in C# are not easily extensible (you'd need to create a copy of the original one combined with what you want to add). Have you considered using a  List<byte> to which you can simply .Add items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Array in C# has a fixed length. You can only set the item of an Array on a Position that the array is long. To have an "Array" that dynamicly extends as you add items to it use a List.

Example:

```
var payload = new List<byte>();
payload.Add(0x00);
```

To obtain an `Array` from the `List` you can call the Linq Extension `payload.ToArray()`